# Mount-WindowsImage Issue

Tags: powershell, winpe

I decided to rewrite my USB boot media to a PowerShell script. When mounting I use the following

```
Mount-WindowsImage -ImagePath X:\DEV.wim -Index 1 -Path "C:\windows"
```

The .WIM is on a separate partition on the boot USB. When called, PowerShell can't see that partition. I am guessing because I am not "working" on that disk.

Is there a way to tell that command to mount a .wim from a separate partition to the disk I am working on?

Example:

```
Mount-WindowsImage -DiskNumber 0 -ImagePath I:\DEV.wim -Index 1 -DiskNumber 1 -Path "C:\windows"
```

Comment: I see that you have X:\DEV.wim, X: is normally reserved for RAM disk partition for WinPE.  Are you manipulating your wim file while running winpe?

Also, you can mount a wim file from a separate partition as long as it's not a network location.  It can be from a removable or fixed drive.  

What is the format of the other partition of the USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

For adding powershell support in your WinPE boot media you need to attach some `.cab` files.

First you need to mount your wim and add a few packages to your `boot.wim` file.

The location for the optional components are as follows for x64 bit.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE\_OCs\
```

32bit optional components are located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\x86\WinPE\_OCs\
```

You can run this script to add the packages you need to use powershell in WinPE.

```
Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"C:\Path\to\image\boot.wim" /Index:1 /MountDir:"C:\mount\path"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-WMI.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-WMI_en-us.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-NetFX.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-NetFX_en-us.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-Scripting.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-Scripting_en-us.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-PowerShell.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-PowerShell_en-us.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-StorageWMI.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-StorageWMI_en-us.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-DismCmdlets.cab"
Dism /Add-Package /Image:"C:\WinPE_amd64_PS\mount" /PackagePath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-DismCmdlets_en-us.cab"
Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:C:\mount\path /Commit
```

Then you will need to recreate your boot media:

```
MakeWinPEMedia /UFD C:\WinPE_amd64_PS <USBDriveLetter>:
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me clarify something.

Comment: @Seth Please do. I will also ask a question, this is for bootable media correct? like you're going to use this to image other machines correct?

Comment: I have not tried creating a directory on my destination partition. I just smacked in \windows because it said it could not mount to the root directory a few attempts ago. So maybe it can see that partition on a different disk its just not seeing that directory.

Comment: Yes this is a boot device. My script nukes the drive, creates partitions and then mounts windows.

Comment: @Seth Does your boot media use the WinPE? I am sorry I thought you were attempting to create/edit boot media my mistake.

Comment: @Seth You will need to add powershell support to your install media first and foremost, have you done that yet?